# Android Foursquare API - How do I register a user for Foursquare in-app

Tags: android, api, authentication, foursquare

I am developing an android app where I require a user to login to there foursquare account.
I plan to do this through the authenticate url.

I am following the example as per the oauth example:
https://github.com/foursquare/android-oauth-example

However, is there a way that I can sign-up a user to Foursquare in-app if they do not have an account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the embedded WebView pattern, the embedded Foursquare page has an option for your user to sign up for Foursquare if they don't already have an account.